# Get stringified object instead of string with text in when Clicked on Quick reply in FB Messenger Channel (BotFramework v3, Nodejs)

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

Today, my bot stopped responding to me when clicking on quick replies in FB Messenger. Instead of getting the payload as a string, it now returns a stringified object with extra fields.

I'm using a bot with a custom dynamic dialog and creating SuggestedAction like this:

```
choices.push(builder.CardAction.postBack(session, "title=Name&params=Some", "Quick Reply Name"));
```

I used to receive the payload as a string "title=Name&params=Some" in Session object like the following:

```
session.message.text
```

But now, in session.message.text, I receive the following string:

```
"{\r\n  \"type\": \"postBack\",\r\n  \"value\": \"title=Name&params=Some\"\r\n}"
```

Has anybody else faced this same issue?

Is this coming from changes in Azure Bot Service? And if so, where can we follow the change log or release notes?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since card action behavior is channel-specific it's much more likely that this relates to a change in the Facebook Messenger platform. You can view their changelog here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/changelog/

I can see there was a change on January 8th. It doesn't mention anything about postBack behavior, but it's still possible that there could be some unintended or undocumented changes that are responsible for the results you're seeing.

It looks like it should be a simple matter to deserialize the JSON and extract the value.

`var payload = JSON.parse(session.message.text).value;`

Comment: Thank you, for answer, I've done exactly the same to parse the payload.
But couldn't find any mentions about changes neither on BotFramework's change log nor Facebook Messenger Platform's  change log

Comment: Well if it's a change in the Azure Bot Service it's not publicly available. Sorry we couldn't find anything.

Comment: Do you want to mark this answer as correct or do you still need help?